# Not able to display the back button on the toolbar

Tags: android, button, toolbar, back

I am not able to get the back button displayed on the toolbar despite trying every trick including invalidating caches etc. As I seem to be wasting my time on something I seem to have overlooked, request help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance. My code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DeliveryActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Activity

```
package com.example.mymallapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Objects;

public class DeliveryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_delivery);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Delivery");


    }  

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        return true;
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

You can try this

Answer (score 1):

Change activity in manifest file to have the back button for the parent

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.mymallapp.DeliveryActivity" 
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.mymallapp.MyParentActivity">

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 (API 15) and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.mymallapp.MyParentActivity" />
</activity>
```

Change `MyParentActivity` to the activity that you want to return back when you hit the home button.

Comment: Hi Jyotish..thanks...I had already set the actionbar as shown in my code snippet.  Also the theme  already has noactionbar.  So,  I think the bug is something else!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

you need to set actionbar first

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

if you get

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

this error you need to change your change that ativity theme to `NoActionBar` in `Manifest`

Did you try this option?

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

once you get the back arrow visible, you need to add the action as below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
        
        // add on backpressed or finish
            finish();}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shiva,  Zain and Jyotish..I tried each of the suggestions but the back arrow simply refuses to appear on the design tab.. Any suggestions?

Comment: hey Venugopal you can check now, edited the answer just now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.. The problem is solved.. While the back button was not visible on the design tab,  it is very much there when I ran the app on the device. Rather surprising!